# Properly work in a duo using GIT

Tags: php, git, netbeans

Me and a friend of mine are starting a project with CodeIgniter. We have never worked in teams before and therefore are very new to this whole VCS thing. I've read a lot of good things about Git since it's decentralized.

Since it's just the two of us, the checkin-checkout process is not a HUGE deal but we would like to keep it professional for further growth. The problem is that we are both very lost on how to use git. Git's documentation is just too much to handle at this point.

So how would we set this up? I assume we develop on our local machines and run it on a local LAMP/WAMP server. If the result is good we push it to the central server right?

**Also how do I get the edited files from my partner? Do I have to manually download those or does git do that (or is there another/better way)?**  (This part is very important since we are developing really quickly now and a lot of things are changing.)

I am working on NetBeans and I can persuade him to do so as well if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Git is really easy to learn, I recommend these tutorials from BitBucket (I learnt from there myself), it will take no more than an hour.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/

Git works by commiting files to a repository, and you can pull files from that if there's a change. The tutorials will explain it all and how to set it up :-).

Answer (score 0):

Git is powerful and how much you get back is proportional to how much you spend time learning it. :-)  It does take some effort to learn about git. Remember it is neither perforce nor SVN.

One of the best tutorials for quick start I will recommend http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html

For eclipse you can use [EGit plugin](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html).  I am sure there is similar one for NetBeans.

About your question on central server, perhaps you can start with http://bitbucket.org which allows you to host free private repository (as long as there are no more than 5 folks using the same repository, then you will have to pay)